# How to calculate the range of integer data types in ANSI C

Tags: c, ansi-c

What is the mathematical formula to calculate the range of signed, unsigned, short and long data types in ANSI C?

Comment: what do you mean by mathematical formula? They should be specified in the standard itself, right?

Comment: Why do you think you need to? These normally reside in limits.h?

Comment: @SouravGhosh i mean calculating the range by my self without using a program.

Comment: I'm not very sure about ANSI, but in general, you don't need a program to calculate, either. They will be defined in the corresponding standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unsigned types have a range from `0` to `2^(effective number of bits used by the type) - 1`

signed types have a implementation defined minimum:

2's complement `-(2^(effective number of bits used by the type - 1))`
all others `-(2^(effective number of bits used by the type - 1) - 1)`

the maximum for signed types is `2^(effective number of bits used by the type - 1) - 1`

`^` is the power function, not the xor.

Comment: */me* wonders how can the *size in bits* be determined in the run/compile-time

Comment: @EugeneSh. `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Oh.. wasn't aware of `CHAR_BIT`. Is it standard?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, it is. In C99 §5.2.4.2.1, defined in limits.h

Comment: "unsigned types have a range from 0 to 2^(size of type in bits) - 1" is not consistent with the C spec as these types may have padding.  Yet such platforms are rare.

Comment: @chux you are right. Is it correct to write `the effective number of bits used by the type`? I never used a system where the standard types have bit padding.

Comment: Agreed - the "size of type in bits" is the sum of the sign, value and padding bits. Note:  "... `signed char` shall not have any padding bits ..." C11 dr §6.2.6.2 2  So other types _may_ have them.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hope it helps
 * C Program to Print the Range~~ Google
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE(x) sizeof(x)*8

void signed_one(int);
void unsigned_one(int);

void main()
{
    printf("\nrange of int");
    signed_one(SIZE(int));
    printf("\nrange of unsigned int");
    unsigned_one(SIZE(unsigned int));
    printf("\nrange of char");
    signed_one(SIZE(char));
    printf("\nrange of unsigned char");
    unsigned_one(SIZE(unsigned char));
    printf("\nrange of short");
    signed_one(SIZE(short));
    printf("\nrange of unsigned short");
    unsigned_one(SIZE(unsigned short));

}
/* RETURNS THE RANGE SIGNED*/
void signed_one(int count)
{
    int min, max, pro;
    pro = 1;
    while (count != 1)
    {
        pro = pro << 1;
        count--;
    }
    min = ~pro;
    min = min + 1;
    max = pro - 1;
    printf("\n%d to %d", min, max);
}
/* RETURNS THE RANGE UNSIGNED */
void unsigned_one(int count)
{
    unsigned int min, max, pro = 1;

    while (count != 0)
    {
        pro = pro << 1;
        count--;
    }
    min = 0;
    max = pro - 1;
    printf("\n%u to %u", min, max);
}
```

Program Explanation

1. Convert the number of bytes into bits by multiplying the bytes with 8.
2. Use two functions namely signed_one() and unsigned_one() for calculating the range of signed and unsigned data types respectively.
3. Value got at step 1 is sent as a parameter to both the functions. In both the function, it is received by variable count.
4. Initialize the variable pro to 1 in both the functions.
5. In the function signed_one() using while loop with the condition (count != 1), shift the variable pro to its left by 1 position and decrement the variable count by 1 consecutively.
6. When the loop terminates, assign the complement of pro to the variable min and increment the min by 1. Decrement the variable pro and assign it to the variable max. Print min and max as output.
7. In the function unsigned_one() using while loop with the condition (count !=0), shift the variable pro to its left by 1 position and decrement the variable count by 1 consecutively.
8. When the loop terminates, assign zero to the variable min. Decrement the variable pro and assign it to the variable max. Print min and max as output.